# SQL join on left 6 charactes

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have got table with CCnumber in format like '441231xxxxxxxxxx' and then table with all Card BIN number which are in format of '441231'

How can I join those two tables?

I have tried:

```
SELECT CardType, COUNT(Transactions.cc) 

FROM CardBin CB
JOIN CreditCardLog CC ON LEFT(CCnumber.CC,6)=BinNumber.CardBin

GROUP BY CardType;
```

I am using MS SQL. Thanks alot.

Comment: `LEFT(CCnumber.CC,6)=BinNumber.CardBin` Huh?  Isn't that backwards?  And not using the alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to use table aliases correctly in your query:

```
SELECT CardType, COUNT(cc.Transactions) 
FROM CardBin CB JOIN 
     CreditCardLog cc
     ON LEFT(cc.CCnumber, 6) = cb.BinNumber
GROUP BY CardType;
```

The table alias goes before the column, in the reference.